# Change running heads in longtable (or other "long table" package)

Tags: longtable

In a longtable, I list items of several categories, including some data on them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lll}
\hline
\textbf{These are some items} & &\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\textbf{These are items of type A} & \textbf{Size} & \textbf{Price}\\
\hline
Item 1 & 3 foot   & 3.56\\
Item 2 & 2 inches & 2.56\\
Item 3 & 5 inches & 1.50\\
\hline
\textbf{These are items of type B} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Price}\\
\hline
Item A & 3 pounds & 10.50\\
Item B & 5 ounces & 6.95\\
Item C & 1 pound  & 3.00\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

What I would *like* to get is to *change* the running head whenever a new category is begun, so that if e.g. there is a page break between Item B and Item C, the header on the next line would read the "These are items of type B" line (so the columns are properly labeled).

Can this be done with `longtable` or any other "long table" package? I couldn't find information on this. (My google-fu is weak today...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly automatic to do this in `supertab` as Irecall as the head in that case is stored as a table and re-set every time, so if you use a `\mark` or just a normal command that you globally define within the table, it will pick up the new definition on each page.

It could be done with `longtable`, and I'm fairly sure that there is some code to do it posted to comp.text.tex somewhere. `longtable` stores the head in a box so normally it has to be fixed throughout the table. However it wouldn't be hard to change its internals so that where it says

```
 \copy\LT@head
```

it instead says

```
\mysavedheadrows
```

where `\mysavedheadrows` were some table lines defined in a command before `longtable` starts.
The man thing that would need to be ensured is that the *vertical* size of the rows is unchanged (`longtable` will get very confused if the size of teh head that is being inserted changes).

Comment: Indeed it is possible to simply use `\tablehead` repeatedly within a `supertabular`, solving my problem.