# Longtable Column Repeat

Tags: longtable, multirow

I am a new LaTeX user, and am using \longtable to create a table that spans several pages.

The items in my leftmost column are titles for the items to the right, and often span up to ten rows (using \multirow}.

I am using the \endhead and \endfoot functions to repeat the headings and footings for the table, however I would also like the text in the leftmost column to be repeated on the next page when the table is split in the middle of the multirow. Is there a function that makes this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your description isn't all that specific. Please post a code example that gives rise to the issue you would like to fix.

Comment: basically, no, sorry. longtable headings are generated at the start and repeated every page but they never change.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384886/longtable-know-if-first-non-header-row-after-page-break